# propagation of sound energy

Tags: acoustics

In my previous questions like 'how do compressions and relaxation carry energy...' and 'how are they not isothermal...' and 'where does the heat come from in the compressed gas...',i've made  enquiries reagarding the phenomenon of sound energy propagation and got answers from experts.So i am now writting my concept:when a vibrating fork compresses the air,it does work on it increasing the K.E. of the layer.When the fork goes opp. side,it works on the compressed layer and relaxes it increasing theP.E.Meanwhile,during expansion,the layer works on the next layer and compresses it using the excess kinetic energy.And the next layer does the same to its next layer by compressing using that K.E. given to it by the fork via the first layer.Ultimately,the last layer works on our ear drum to produce sound using the kinetic energy.The question is am i right in my assumption?Plz help...

Comment: If i m right just tell me,it's urgent and plz don't mark it as duplicate or anything else.I need clarification in my concept.If i m wrong,just amend the explanation.It will be a great help.Thnk u...

Comment: Pl. O wmat ,alr as di[;ocate/  Os tjat PLz?  Thnk u...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the compression and expansion of air propagate sound energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99531/)

Comment: This question is also asked by me .Why it is duplicate simply depends on u.I ve mentiond that i ve earlier asked quite similar questions and after getting answers,i ve reshaped my conception & posted this.Just tell am i right?It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, although the first layer already works on the second layer during compression